# Passing multiple variable for php page

Tags: php

Hey guys I need help on passing multiple values for my PHP

http://s596.beta.photobucket.com/user/kingbookal/media/Capture.png.html?sort=3&o=0

That's the code from the 1st page and for the next page it is

```
$year = $_GET['yearlevel'];
```

I tried to alert the value but its null.

Please guide me well..

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fokl2hnrjtpsfbn/Rcm8EfApm1
This is the link for my scripts

Comment: What are you trying to do? doesn't have enough information to debug your question

Comment: Can you post your full html and php? I have no idea what context these two lines of code are in. (i.e. are they in the same file, different files, different pages, different domains, etc.) You didn't provide enough information to get help.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Try being more specific and maybe post some more code.

Comment: If your parameter values are not passing in the link, enclose them in curly braces. i.e ?evalid={$rowProfName[user_id]}

Comment: i will post the whole page wait

Comment: on the next page, try printing out the whole `$_GET` array to see what got passed using `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fokl2hnrjtpsfbn/Rcm8EfApm1

Comment: i didnt use array for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to echo the value from a key inside an array? Then you do like this:

```
echo $rowProfName['professor_name'];
```

If it doesn't return anything, you could check if a key exists in the array by using the following code:

```
if(!isset($rowProfName['professor_name']))
{
    echo "Array key 'professor_name' is not set.";
}
```

If you want to check what your array contains, simply run this code:

```
$yourArray=array("value1","value2");

print_r($yourArray);

//If you want clean output as HTML, use this:
echo "<pre>";
print_r($yourArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

I hope I understood your question.